# How to use JSON and HTTP POST in Laravel to work with a ticketing API

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to implement a JSON payload to create a ticket using HTTP POST and this API(https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/develop/setup/doc/api.md) in my PHP application (using Laravel framework) and I'm at an utter loss as to how to start attacking this problem. any insight?

I currently have a form built with laravel that will collect user data through a form. My goal is to take the data from said form, populate the fields on a JSON payload (the one I have below is from the API's github page) and then submit the ticket to the system when the "submit form" button is hit. Literally any help at all or advice would be greatly appreciated

This is what the JSON payload would look like but I also don't know where in laravel to put it/how to format it.

```
{
    "alert": true,
    "autorespond": true,
    "source": "API",
    "name": "Angry User",
    "email": "randoemail@gmail.com",
    "phone": "3333333333",
    "subject": "Testing API",
    "ip": "123.211.233.122",
    "message": "data:text/html,MESSAGE <b>HERE</b>",
   }
```

Comment: Are you getting this payload from the API? or is this what the customer submits into the ticketing system? Please clarify the order of events and what you wish to capture when.

Comment: I currently have a form built with laravel that will collect user data through a form. My goal is to take the data from said form, populate the fields on a JSON payload (the one I have above is from the API's github page) and then submit the ticket to the system when the "submit form" button is hit

Comment: well, I suggest to you: make a ticket, see what fields in the pristine database it popuplates and sets to its values.  Then mimic that with laravel models set to the database fields of the ticketing system.

Comment: I know what fields to populate and how to put that in laravel, I'm just a bit lost as to how to translate that into json and http post (I've never used either)

Comment: if you popuplate the fields, you don't need the post... the ticketing system will think it was injected by the or whatever method.

Comment: The form I built is separate from the ticketing system. I'm a bit confused as to what you're getting at. I'm trying to implement the ticketing system's API to submit tickets into the ticketing system from the form that I built that currently has no connection to the ticketing system

Comment: Your form submits to your laravel controller > Your laravel controller `$ticket = TicketItem::create(post('formcontents'))` where TicketItem is your laravel model to *mock* the ticket database. Then when you login to the ticket system it will simply see a new unassigned ticket.

Comment: gotcha, I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like so (No other stuff required):

Create an osTicket lib somewhere (I've placed it in app/Library)

```
namespace App\Library;

class osTicket {

  protected $url;

  protected $apikey;

  protected $topicid;

  public function __construct($apikey = null, $url = null, $ip = null) {
    $this->url = env('TICKET_URL', $url);
    $this->apikey = env('TICKET_APIKEY', $apikey);
    $this->ip = env('TICKET_IP', $ip);
  }

  public function createTicket($name, $email, $phone, $subject, $message) {
    $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'message' => $message,
            'ip' => $this->ip,
            [whatever other stuff you've configured in your OSticket, e.g. product_id, list_id, etc. - just pass appropriate variable]
    );

    function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');
    function_exists('json_encode') or die('JSON support required');
    set_time_limit(30);
    $ch = curl_init();
    //not everything below is needed. depends on you
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.8');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$this->apikey));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
  }

}
```

Setup your variables in .env:

```
TICKET_URL=http://xxxxxxxx.com/api/http.php/tickets.json
TICKET_APIKEY={api_key_here}
TICKET_IP={your_ip}
```

Then pass along form post data to your Controller like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Library\osTicket;
use Auth;
use User;

class WhateverController extends Controller {
public function addticket(Request $request) {

      $user = User::find(Auth::id());
      $ticket = new osTicket;
      $ticket->createTicket($user->name, $user->email, $user->phone, $request->subject, $request->message);
      if($result === true) {

          return back();

        } else {

          return back()->with('status', $result);

        }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do should work by going through two steps

1. Build a PHP dict/array with the desired values, then (depending on the HTTP library - see below) convert that to JSON. Something like this in your controller method:

```
$dict['alert'] = $request->input('alert');
$dict['autorespond'] = $request->input('autorespond');
...
$json = json_encode($dict);
```

Alternaively if there is no content that should not be posted to the API you can do:

```
$json = json_encode($request->all());
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

2. Once you have your json you need an http library to perform the request. Laravel recommends Guzzle so you would do something like:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://github.com.com/whatever/']);
$response = $client->post('the/api/endpoint', ['json' => $request->all()]);
```

Note that you don't need to `json_encode` the content here as Guzzle will do that for you.
See: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

From there handle the data however you need.

Comment: Thank you so much! This gives me a great place to stem from, I appreciate it

Comment: with the ['json' => $request->all()]); Would I change that to read json => $dict if I just wanted to use what I had put in the dict variable?

Comment: Yep! Guzzle will happily convert the dict into a json object for you.